# Report of all lists/libraries and documents where a particular keyword in available

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, powershell, reports, keywordquery

One of our monitoring tool is getting replaced by another tool.

So I need to generate a report all lists items/libraries and documents where the old tool name is referred and take action. I have to check this in both SharePoint Online and SharePoint 2013 on-prem farms.

Possible to get this report as excel in OOB or using PS script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you wish to generate a report on search result of certain keyword (old tool name)?

If that is the scenario, here is a sample script for SharePoint on-premises:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 
#Set Parameters
$SiteURL = "http://sp"
$CSVFile = "C:\Temp\SearchResults.csv"
$SearchQuery = "<old tool name>"
 
#Get the site collection
$Site = Get-SPSite $SiteURL
 
#Frame Query to search: Get all documents sorted by Last modified
$keywordQuery = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.KeywordQuery($Site)
$keywordQuery.QueryText = $SearchQuery
$keywordQuery.SortList.Add("LastModifiedTime","Asc")
 
#Execute Search
$SearchExecutor = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor
$searchResults = $SearchExecutor.ExecuteQuery($keywordQuery)
 
#Get Search Results
$Table = $SearchResults.Table
$Table | select Title, Path, Author, LastModifiedTime
 
#Export Search results to Excel
$Table | Export-Csv $CSVFile -NoTypeInformation
 
Write-Host -f Green "Search Results Exported to CSV File!"
```

And for SharePoint Online:

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.dll"
 
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://crescenttech.sharepoint.com/"
$SearchQuery = "<old tool name>"
$CSVFile = "C:\Temp\SearchResults.csv"
 
Try {
    $Cred= Get-Credential
    $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)
  
    #Setup the context
    $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
    $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
     
    #Define Keyword
    $KeywordQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery($Ctx)
    $KeywordQuery.QueryText = $SearchQuery
    $KeywordQuery.RowLimit  = 500
    $keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("CreatedBy")
    $keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("LastModifiedTime")
    $keywordQuery.SortList.Add("LastModifiedTime","Asc")
 
    #Execute Search       
    $SearchExecutor = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor($Ctx)
    $SearchResults = $SearchExecutor.ExecuteQuery($KeywordQuery)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
 
    Write-host "Search Results Found:"$SearchResults.Value[0].ResultRows.Count
 
    #Get Search Results
    If($SearchResults) {
        $Results = @()
        foreach($Result in $SearchResults.Value[0].ResultRows) {
            $Results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                'Document Name' =  $Result["Title"]
                'URL' = $Result["Path"]
                'Created By' = $Result["CreatedBy"] 
                'Last Modified' = $Result["LastModifiedTime"]              
            }
        }
        $Results
        
        #Export search results to CSV
        $Results | Export-Csv $CSVFile -NoTypeInformation
        Write-Host -f Green "Search Results Exported to CSV File!"
    }
}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error Getting Search Results!" $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Note: If you don’t specify site URL in the search query, it will generate a report at web application/tenant scope.

References:

[PowerShell to Search SharePoint and Export Results to CSV using Keyword Query.](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/02/powershell-to-search-sharepoint-export-results-using-keyword-query.html)

[SharePoint Online: Find All Documents using Keyword Query PowerShell.](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/02/sharepoint-online-find-all-documents-using-keyword-query-powershell.html)